# Accessibility and Keyboard Access for Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

We are implementing Team Foundation Server for a better alternative over Microsoft Office for Work Item Tracking, Requirements gathering, etc.  I am thrilled to have our team implement this, as I have used it in many of my past projects.  That said, we are having some logistical problems implementing the solution.

One of my team members is a blind developer.  He can successfully develop using SQL Developer, Eclipse and other programming software.  However, we are having difficulty figuring out the Team Foundation Server interface using JAWs and pure keyboard access.

We originally tried to use the Visual Studio Online interface, which proved to be completely inaccessible.  He installed the Team Foundation Server client, which seems to be significantly more accessible, but it is still difficult to navigate, especially with multiple panes of information and navigating between the sections of functionality.

We searched online for keyboard shortcut charts, accessibility, etc. and have found a few resources.  However, none of them have solved the problem yet.  Do any of you have any suggestions for how to make it more accessible?  Is there a keyboard shortcut scheme for accessibility that we can interface?  Have you found any good resources online for accessibility shortcuts with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server clients?

Thank you for your help.  We are up for any solution, whether it be a Team Foundation Explorer Everywhere plugin, standalone clients, etc.

Answer (score 3):

We do have keyboard shortcuts for the clients. For Team Explorer (standalone or VS), you can find the list at http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/. We also do accessibility testing for TE/VS, including with JAWS. I watched a video in October that one of the teams had put together to show improvements that they had made. The before was pretty bad and the after was significantly better (and doing the work was motivated by another team at Microsoft who pointed out the shortcomings in trying to use it). The changes went into Update 4 of VS 2013. That's going to provide the best experience we have available. Please give that a try, and let me know what you think.

[Update] Also, we have a handful of key bugs in the web UI that we are working on that in the next month or so will improve the web UI experience in VSO and TFS 2015.

[Update] Here's a [list of the current shortcuts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Overview/reference/keyboard-shortcuts), which includes both the web UI and Team Explorer.

Comment: We were using Visual Studio 2012 due to some corporate Security Policy Issues - we kept getting a 'will not install correctly due to not being able to install security updates' or something along those lines.  It's great to hear that VS2013 is updated though - I'll try to get our Security Team to allow the updates to go through so he can use that.  I'm pretty sure they will allow that since it is for accessibility reasons.  I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post this for others researching this issue. I am a blind programmer who uses the jaws for windows version 17 screen reader. The corporation I work for just installed team foundation server 2015 for teams to use as a scrum project management tool.

The web interface is not useable by me. While some of it is accessible, meaning some links and web page elements are spoken to me and can be clicked, it is not useable in a practical sense. The entire web interface is a drag and drop interface that requires the use of a mouse and does not have any keyboard support to drag and drop items. For example, dragging PBI's into a feature or sprint is not supported by the keyboard or web page elements like html buttons you could click to move PBI's from the back log, to a sprint, to in progress, to completed, etc.

In aiddition, the tree control used is not accessible and is used for quite a bit of web page tasks. I think the tree control used is probably a jquery or javascript item.

The visual studio 2015 team viewer option is somewhat accessible, but it does not appear to allow you to perform all the tasks that the web interface does perform. For example, creating features, creating sprints, moving PBI's into a sprint, etc. If those options are present, and are accessible, I cannot find easily how to do it using the vs 2015 team viewer client.

Overall, while some of the features in the vs 2015 client and also in the web interface are spoken, tfs 2015 is not useable in a practical sense and does not allow a blind programmer to be as fluent as a sighted person using the tfs system. So at this point, I am not able to use the tfs system and must rely on sighted team members to key in my PBI's and drag / drop and create sprints for me. Very disappointing.